# How to forward all requests to an IIS7 server to a new IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, redirect

I have an old physical server and a new physical server.  I am moving everything from my old server to the new server. And will then point my domain registrar records to point to the IP address of the new server. However it may take up to 48 hours for the DNS records to propagate.  In that time some users will hit the old server. I want to have the old server redirect all traffic to the new server.  How do I do this? I have been told to turn the old server to a proxy for the new server or to use the IIS rewrite module.  What is better? What is the industry standard here?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I do this, I also change the TTL on the A record to be changed to be fairly short, and leave it there, otherwise unchanged, for at least the period of the original TTL.  This way, when you change the A record to the new IP, compliant DNS servers and clients will take only the new TTL's time to converge.  (Note: when you change the A record's IP address, also change the TTL back to its original value.)

Caveat: there are a lot of non-compliant DNS servers out there that will ignore your TTL, and a lot of them are run by prominent ISPs.  There's nothing you can really do about this, but at least you can help out those people who use correct DNS servers.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a hardware firewall in between your servers and your ISP, you could just use a NAT rule to forward traffic for the old IP on port 80/443 to the new server.

Comment: My limited understanding is that a NAT rule is set at the router level.  These servers at a data center. I dont have access to their routers.

Comment: You're correct, in which case my suggestion is a no-go.